# Using Doctrine without a framework like symfony

Tags: php

I've used Doctrine together with frameworks like Symfony or Zend. Is there a way to use it without such a framework, with plain, core php?

Comment: @hek2mgl : Where did you learn speaking shmaloupknak ?

Comment: Come on guys, this is obviously a new user, lets not smash them with downvotes just yet. Try to edit the post to make your question clearer. Remember, this is about coding issues predominantly, and we won't Google things for you, you have to show you've actually researched and tried to find a solution yourself

Answer (score 8):

> I've used Doctrine together with frameworks like simfony or zend. Is there a way to use it without such a framework, with plain php?

OF course. you start here , right from the doc :

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

What i mean is you should really have a look at the doctrine doc if you did not.

Comment: +1: a nice way to say "RTFM!"

Comment: Thank you :) "danielhanly.com"

Comment: Except, the 'current' version of that doc installs (bits of) symfony: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/tutorials/getting-started.html